# MySQL/Java: Adding the results of a SELECT COUNT to the result of another SELECT COUNT

Tags: java, mysql

This intro might seem long and unnecessary, but it is important to understand the conditions. I've been at this for several hours and I can't seem to find a solution. I'm using Java so using multiple queries and calculating it in Java is also a solution, but not the most efficient one. Keep in mind that I'm a mere IT student.

I've ran into quite the headache of a problem with my SQL. 
My current project is a game of Mastermind. There is an option to challenge another player. In this mode, both players play the same game with the same solution and aim to solve it in the least amount of tries. 
To do this, you first select a difficulty level. With this information, you get a list of possible opponents. A difficulty level is only unlocked when you won at least 20 challenges of the previous difficulty level. A draw is in favor of the challenger.

For each challenge, the usernames of both the challenger and challenged, the difficulty level,  the number of tries needed for both and the solution.
To get this list, we need to calculate the amount of won games for each player. If that player has more than 20 won challenges, they are added to the list. 
The difficulty in this is that you have to calculate both the amount of wins where the player is the challenger and where they are the challenged.

The Create statement for this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Challenge` (
`numberOfTriesChallenger` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`numberOfTriesChallenged` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`difficulty` int(11) NOT NULL,
`usernameChallenger` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`usernameChallenged` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`solution` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`difficulty`,`usernameChallenger`,`usernameChallenged`),
KEY `usernameChallenger_idx` (`usernameChallenger`),
KEY `usernameChallenged_idx` (`usernameChallenged`),
CONSTRAINT `usernameChallenger` FOREIGN KEY (`usernameChallenger`) 
REFERENCES `Player` (`username`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `usernameChallenged` FOREIGN KEY (`usernameChallenged`) 
REFERENCES `Player` (`username`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

If done entirely in SQL, the ResultSet should be the list of usernames of the players that won more than 20 challenges.

For those asking for the queries I've tried, none come even close to the result I need.

Comment: You can [edit] your question. Please show us your query.

Comment: I don't have any queries. I simply have no idea how to do this. It isn't a matter of not trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query will probably do what you want. It will give you a list of users and their number of wins as challenger or challenged, as well as total at each difficulty level. The `HAVING` clause at the end will limit the results to those users with total wins at that difficulty level >= 20. The various `IFNULL` and `IS NULL` pieces are to deal with the end cases where a player may not have played as Challenger or Challenged.

```
SELECT p.username AS User,
  COALESCE(c1.difficulty, c2.difficulty) AS Difficulty,
  IFNULL(c1.ChallengerWins, 0) AS ChallengerWins,
  IFNULL(c2.ChallengedWins, 0) AS ChallengedWins,
  IFNULL(c1.ChallengerWins, 0) + IFNULL(c2.ChallengedWins, 0) AS TotalWins
FROM Player p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT c1.usernameChallenger AS User,
             difficulty,
             SUM(CASE WHEN c1.numberOfTriesChallenger <= c1.numberOfTriesChallenged THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ChallengerWins
           FROM Challenge c1
           GROUP BY User, difficulty) c1
ON c1.User = p.username
LEFT JOIN (SELECT c2.usernameChallenged AS User,
             difficulty,
             SUM(CASE WHEN c2.numberOfTriesChallenger > c2.numberOfTriesChallenged THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ChallengedWins
           FROM Challenge c2
           GROUP BY User, difficulty) c2
ON c2.User = p.username AND (c2.difficulty = c1.difficulty OR c1.difficulty IS NULL)
GROUP BY User, Difficulty
HAVING Difficulty IS NOT NULL AND TotalWins >= 20
```

Sample output from [a small example I made up](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ee2e6/6):

```
User    Difficulty  ChallengerWins  ChallengedWins  TotalWins
Fred    2           1               2               3
Jim     1           2               1               3
Jim     2           0               2               2
Nick    1           1               1               2
```

If you want to restrict the results to a given difficulty level, add a

```
WHERE c1.difficulty = <difficulty-level>
```

clause before the `GROUP BY` and remove `Difficulty` from the `GROUP BY` e.g.

```
WHERE c1.difficulty = 2
GROUP BY User
```

Comment: The calculations aren't correct. It gives more wins than there are records for a certain player

Comment: Hmmm... it works fine on my small example. Can you post a fiddle with some data that shows it not working?

Comment: Scrap that, it actually does work! I thought I inserted more than 20 records for another player but I only added 19. Also I miscounted the number of wins so of course it would give the impression of the calculations being off.
Thanks man! How long did you work on this?

Comment: It took a little while. But I don't mind, I'm always learning stuff from answering questions that helps me when I do my own coding. And the little green badge when I get reputation always makes it worth while! :)

Comment: You're a real lifesaver man. This might save my whole project and my grade. The Use Case the professor made was quite unclear so we had to make do but turned out we were wrong and had to rework quite a lot of code. Couple that with 1 of my teammates ghosting us. Group project can be such a pain sometimes.

Comment: Don't get me started on group projects! Worst experience of my life. Pretty sure they only brought them in to torture students ( and to make the lecturers life easy since they have less work to mark)

Comment: Small edit for the query. When a challenge isn't finished, either one or both columns for numberOfTries will be 0. Do I add a 'AND numberOfTriesX!=0' in the WHEN clause in the subqueries?

Comment: One last request. How can I select the number of games a single player won for each difficulty level?

Comment: For the first question, yes I think adding a `AND numberOfTriesX` != 0 in the `WHEN` clause should work. For the second part, just remove the `HAVING` clause and you will get all results for all players.

Comment: So removing the HAVING clause will get all the results. How exactly do I specify it should only show the result for a single player? With all those aliases, I'm not sure which username to use in the WHERE

Comment: add a `WHERE p.username=name` just before the `GROUP BY` (same place as I suggested putting a check on difficulty in the answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170784/discussion-between-nick-lersberghe-and-nick).